# Fullcalendar 4.x - Adding header "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Using Fullcalendar 4.x, is it possible to add the "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" header when fetching events ?

I'm setting up the event source in this way :

```
calendar.addEventSource({ url: ev_url, id: 'default' });
```

Everything works and the request is sent correctly, but the header i mentioned is missing (on server side we require that header to be present).

I tried adding the following to addEventSource:

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
}
```

Another thing i tried was to add this in the js file (probably pointless since Fullcalendar 4 is not using jquery anymore ?):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
  }
});
```

Unfortunately neither solution worked.

In the past when using fullcalendar 3.x that header was present when requesting events. I guess that was because JQuery was adding it automatically.

Comment: It looks like you can't specify the headers through the API when using just a URL as the event source. I think you'd have to implement the events-as-a-function pattern instead and handle the AJAX code yourself. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the answer to this as well. I modified the FullCalendar main.js file which is not ideal but does the trick!

I modified the file @ around line 4242 here is the full source from that function:

```
 /*! FullCalendar Core Package v4.3.1

    function requestJson(method, url, params, successCallback, failureCallback) {
    method = method.toUpperCase();

    // Set Headers From Params to own varaible
    var headers;
    if(params.hasOwnProperty('headers') && Array.isArray(params.headers)){
      headers = params.headers;
      // Remove them from the params object
      delete params.headers;
    }

    var body = null;
    if (method === 'GET') {
        url = injectQueryStringParams(url, params);
    }
    else {
        body = encodeParams(params);
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url, true);        

    // Create Headers If Avaiable
    if(typeof headers !== "undefined"){
        for(var key in headers){
          if (!headers.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
            var obj = headers[key];
            for(var prop in obj){
                if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
                xhr.setRequestHeader(prop, obj[prop]);
            }
        }           
    }

    if (method !== 'GET') {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    }

    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400) {
            try {
                var res = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                successCallback(res, xhr);
            }
            catch (err) {
                failureCallback('Failure parsing JSON', xhr);
            }
        }
        else {
            failureCallback('Request failed', xhr);
        }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function () {
        failureCallback('Request failed', xhr);
    };
    xhr.send(body);
}
```

To Use it I simply add a headers key to the extraParams object like so:

```
extraParams = {
        action: 'get_event',
        headers: [
            {"X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"}
        ]
};
```

This way you can add as many extra headers as you need.